# What is the maximum length of a string parameter to Stored procedure?

Tags: sql

I have a string of length 1,44,000 which has to be passed as a parameter to a stored procedure which is a select query on a table.
When a give this is in a query (in c# ) its working fine. But when i pass it as a parameter to stored procedure its not working.

Here is my stored procedure where in i have declared this parameter as NVARCHAR(MAX)

```
------------------------------------------------------
set ANSI_NULLS ON
set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
go

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ReadItemData](@ItemNames NVARCHAR(MAX),@TimeStamp as DATETIME)

AS

select * from ItemData

where ItemName in (@ItemNames) AND TimeStamp=@TimeStamp

---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Here the parameter @ItemNames is a string concatinated with different names such as 
'Item1','Item2','Item3'....etc.

Can anyone tell what went wrong here?

Thanks & Regards

Padma

Comment: The maximum length of a string parameter to a stored procedure probably depends on the database. Are you using SQL Server? Which version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the looks of the database syntax it looks like Sql Server, [these are the maximum sizes of things in Sql Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx).

```
Bytes per short string column 8,000
```

Is probably the limiter.

Although:

> Bytes per varchar(max),
>   varbinary(max), xml, text, or image
>   column  2^31-1

(i.e. 2,147,483,647) suggests that Sql Server would handle it but for ado.net.

Comment: though the size limit is 2^31-1, its not taking this parameter which is given as follows from the code:

  command.Parameters.Add("@ItemNames",SqlDbType.VarChar).Value=itemNames.ToString();

Comment: I don't think that the limiter is Sql Server, in this instance - but ADO.NET.  I remember (back in the day) when I was using ADO/VBScript there was a limit of about 8,040 bytes for a recordset - I'll see if I can find a reference, but there may well be a cumulative limit for input or output parameters on ADO.NET

Comment: OK, so just to be clear, there are about 1000 bytes per character

Comment: @boulder_ruby Is this a joke that went over my head? I was under the impression that a character is anywhere from 1-4 bytes (depending on charset/OS/language/whatever...).

Answer (score 5):

I realize this is an old question, but the problem that I see is not one of field limitation, but syntax.  The problem is that the stored procedure does not treat the parameter as a string to be inserted into the SELECT text, but is literally looking for the presence of the 1M+ string in your field.  There are a couple of ways to deal with this.

First, you can build the SQL dynamically in a variable, and then run it like this:

```
DECLARE @SQL as nvarchar(max)
SET @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM ItemData WHERE ItemName in (' + @ItemsNames + ')'
         + ' AND TimeStamp = ''' + @TimeStamp + ''''
EXEC (@SQL)
```

However, this will still fail, because @ItemNames has embedded quotes in it, causing the resultant SQL to be invalid.  You might be able to change the @ItemNames with:

```
REPLACE(@ItemNames, '''', '''''')
```

but I haven't tested this.  The idea here is that you are writing escaped single-quotes ('') in the string text to send a single single-quote (') to the query processor.  The REPLACE function above is looking inside the text for any single-quotes, and replacing them with two single-quotes.

A more robust solution would be to create a Split table-valued function, then change your IN clause with something like:

```
WHERE ItemName IN (SELECT SplitText FROM dbo.Split(@ItemNames))
```

I am assuming that you are taking care of the embedded quotes within the Split function.  I don't recommend just removing quotes with a REPLACE, since the quotes might be protecting commas within the string value.

Answer (score 1):

Maximum you can pass 8000 characters in `VARCHAR(MAX)` property and 4000 characters in `NVARCAHR(MAX)`

If you want to pass more then that then you need to use User Define Table Type as a parameter.

Step 1: Need to create User Define Table Type.

```
CREATE TYPE udtt_ItemNames AS TABLE 
(
    Item nvarchar(100)    
)
```

Step 2: User the udtt_ItemNames into store Procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ReadItemData](@ItemNames udtt_ItemNames readonly,@TimeStamp as DATETIME)

AS

select * from ItemData

where ItemName in (select Item from @ItemNames) AND TimeStamp=@TimeStamp
```

So now you need to pass Table while execute the store procedure.